# AVFoundation Record Video for web playback -- has to download WHOLE file before playback starts

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, video, avfoundation

I have an iPad app that records video and sends it to my SaaS application using AVFoundation. My web application then reads the file, and plays it using JWPlayer.

The problem I am having, is that JWPlayer (or any player I have tried) has to download the WHOLE video file before it will play. After doing some reading, I have discovered that the videos recorded from IOS don't have "fast start from internet" enabled. Or something along those lines.

I am using AVFoundation. Is there a different way to save the video so it will stream instantly from my web server? What am I missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAssetWriter/shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse) property on `AVWriter` allows you to do this.

You could use it to rewrite the captured movie file prior to uploading to your server (or immediately post-capture, whatever suits I suppose).

**Edit:**

Okay, I'm not at a Mac at the moment, but something along these lines:

```
AVAsset *originalFile = [AVAsset assetWithURL:originalFileURL];

NSURL *outputFileURL = wherever you want to put it;

NSError *readerError;  

NSError *writerError;

AVAssetReader *reader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:originalFile error:&readerError];

AVAssetWriter *writer = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:outputFileURL fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&writerError];

writer.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

[writer startWriting];

...
```

and so on.

Comment: Do you have any sample code? To open the captured file, and re-save it with those settings? I would really appreciate it.